# Apache rewrite rules doesn't work only with particular prefix

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I've some problem with a script I'm writing.

I have those kind of URLs:

```
forum.php?f=topic&g=$1&id=$2&alias=$3
forum.php?f=group&g=$1
forum.php
```

I need to rewrite those for have:

```
/forum/group/id-alias_topic > forum.php?f=topic&g=[GROUP]&id=[ID]&alias=[ALIAS_TOPIC]
/forum/group > forum.php?f=group&g=[GROUP]
/forum > forum.php
```

I tried with:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([\w'-]+)/([0-9]+)-([\w'-]+) forum.php?f=topic&g=$1&id=$2&alias=$3
RewriteRule ^forum/([\w'-]+) forum.php?f=group&g=$1
RewriteRule ^forum/ forum.php
```

But it doesn't work. It shows me only forum.php
Every URL starting with `/forum` shows me the default page provided by `/forum.php`

For example, `forum.php` will show the text "MAIN PAGE".

`forum.php?f=topic&g=[GROUP]&id=[ID]&alias=[ALIAS_TOPIC]` should show me "GROUP + ID + ALIAS_TOPIC"

But if I visit `/forum/android/1-first_topic` it shows me "MAIN PAGE"

If I replace `^forum` with, for example `^foru`, it works.
I've cleaned my browser cache and restarted apache, but it still doesn't work.
Also with other browsers the problem is the same.
In my /var/www there are those files and directories:

```
administrator.php  assets  cache  forum_functions.php  forum.php  functions.php  global.php  index.php  media  notfound.php  OLD  pwdgen.php  robots.txt  rss.php  simple_html_dom.php  store.php  template  v.php
```

Do you have some advice?

Rewrite.log: http://pastebin.com/MeapYeBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution thanks to @Michael Berkowski

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

and remove all occurrences of MultiViews, then restart apache.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have not used the `[L]` (last) flag and not anchored the end of the expressions with `$` each one matches the last rule after dropping through the first two.

For example, this URL will match both the first and last rules: `example.com/forum/group/123-thing` because the last rule matches `forum/` and *anything* that follows it if not terminated by `$`.

Add `[L]` flags to prevent fall-through, and terminate the regex with `$`

```
# Don't apply these if the file actually exists (like forum.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# This one doesn't really need to terminate in $
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)-(.+) forum.php?f=topic&g=$1&id=$2&alias=$3 [L]
# This one must terminate with $
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]+)$ forum.php?f=group&g=$1 [L]
# As must this one..
RewriteRule ^forum/?$ forum.php [L]
```

I have also replaced your `[\w'-]+` with a simpler `[^/]+` to match everything up to the next `/`. In the last rule, I added `/?` to allow for an optional trailing `/`.  It will work just as well with `[\w'-]+`, but since you intend to match everything between `/`, `[^/]+` is a more common pattern.

Each of the above rules is tested and working over at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Your code doesn't work... I think there is some problem with my server, if I remove .htaccess and if I visit /forum/ it works, but how can without .htaccess if my /forum.php isn't into /forum/ but into / ?

Comment: My error.log say only notices about PHP variables not defined in my PHP script. There isn't anything about .htaccess.
I tried your last code without success. I've added info about files and folders in my document root.

Comment: And finally, this .htaccess file belongs at `/`, not in any subdirectory.

Comment: If I visit administrator.php it works. If I visit /forum/* it shows me the page that should show /forum.php. Yes, .htaccess is into root.

Comment: No, I mean that it shows me the /forum.php without correct parameters.

Comment: @FezVrasta Debug by adding `[L,R=301]` to force each to redirect. Then you will see if Apache matched the rule, and determine if PHP has a fault elsewhere. Isolated, the rules I have above _will_ work in Apache.

Comment: I've added R=301 to each line but it doesn't redirect anything, it shows me "MAIN PAGE" if I visit /forum or /forum/* without redirects...

Comment: Do you have other rewrite rules, and have you added `$` as suggested?  I just tested your url `/forum/android/1-first_topic` on my own and it worked correctly.  Comment out the two RewriteCond when testing.

Comment: Wait, if it shows you `MAIN PAGE` from `/forum` _without_ redirect in the presence of `[R=301]`, then you have some other rule somewhere getting in the way of this.

Comment: I'm using your code, adding (RewriteEngine On) on the top, commented RewriteCond and it doesn't works, it shows me only "MAIN PAGE"...
My .htaccess is only the one provided by you, without anything else... **edit:** If I replace in your code *forum* with *foru* it works.. why?

Comment: Comment _all lines_ in the .htaccess and see what behavior you get. I really believe you have something else interfering at the server or directory level that I cannot help you debug. You need to watch your access logs and enable RewriteLog to see what matches. You need to test by adding leading `/` as in `^/forum...` to the rules (though it should not be present in htaccess).

Comment: Seems a Cache related problem, with /foru instead of /forum your rules works fine, but if I visit **/forum** it shows me "MAIN PAGE", but atm I've not a rule that match **/forum** into my .htaccess. And I'm cleaning my browser cache and trying with different browsers. **edit:** Now I try your advice.

Comment: I've added to the question my rewrite.log

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24594/discussion-between-fez-vrasta-and-michael-berkowski)

Answer (score 0):

You Must put skip flag for stop other  rules  With tihs  **[S]** at end of RewriteRule like

```
 RewriteRule ^forum/([\w'-]+)/([0-9]+)-([\w'-]+)$ forum.php?f=topic&g=$1&id=$2&alias=$3 [S=2]
 RewriteRule ^forum/([\w'-]+)$ forum.php?f=group&g=$1 [S=1]
 RewriteRule ^forum/$ forum.php
```

Comment: Thx, your code doesn't work, it return me the same behavior of my code.